# What does the conjunction As describe in this passage?

Tags: expressions

I'm not a native English speaker, so I have to find a solution for what I don't understand.  sometimes a conjunction like AS is used in different ways which requires attention, so I go to stackexchange for what I don't know to find a solution.  In English, when you read the news or journal, you will see something that you have not learned before.  After that, what does the conjunction "As" mean?

1: As the first transgender volunteer in the Israeli Police, activist Efrat Tilma answers emergency calls and works to improve the relationship between police forces and the community.

2: As the civil war in Yemen has grown more violent this year, lawyer Maeen Al-Obaidi continues to be focused on peace building in the besieged city of Taiz.

Comment: -1 You asked the same question yesterday.

Comment: Yes, I still haven't found a solution

Comment: Your previous question was closed with the reason "Please include the research you’ve done, or consider if your question suits our English Language Learners site better. Questions that can be answered using commonly-available references are off-topic." If you don't understand a use of a word, your first stop should be a dictionary (or more than one dictionaries). These uses of "as" are covered in any good dictionary, and there is nothing strange here. Please look in a dictionary, and then if you still don't understand, explain what you read and what is giving you trouble.

Comment: As @StuartF says, this is dictionary stuff.